# Sha256 checksum on terminal displaying strange characters

Tags: ubuntu, checksum, elementaryos

I've installed the `hashalot` first to use the sha256.
 Then something  strange happened when using the command + filename:

```
mlockall: Cannot allocate memory
Warning: couldn't lock memory, are you root?
Enter passphrase:
```

I've never needed to enter passphrase before for this as far as I remember. And if I do provide a password or use `sudo` before running the command I get strange characters on result:

```
��z�9��E-�c���F�K��"�x~�(8�J��
```

I am on an OS based on Ubuntu (Elementary OS Freya).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you read the description of the package you installed?

> This program will read a passphrase from standard input and print a binary (not printable) hash to standard output.

You tried to print the output to console; what you're seeing is expected behavior.

Comment: Well, I just found out that what I was exactly looking for is sha256sum! That's why the use of it in the past was different... And I am learning about Linux and even computing, so I don't really understand the purpose of sha256 only. But from now on I'll start reading as many man pages as possible!

Your answer did help me dig further and get where I wanted :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why would this be expected behavior? It prints that warning even using the `-x` switch to print the output as hex, which suggests that this answer is incorrect. I believe the better (closer to correct) answer is [Jeffrey Gong's](https://superuser.com/a/1202347).

Answer (score 4):

ubuntu 16.04 default max shared memory per user is 64k. I upped it to
1gb for all users, error goes away.

by adding a line to the end of the /etc/security/limits.conf file will fix this. no need to reboot the system, you'll need to logout though.

```
$ echo test  | sha256 -s test | base64
mlockall: Cannot allocate memory
Warning: couldn't lock memory, are you root?
NyaDNd1pMQRb3N+SYj/4GaZCRLU9DnRtQ4eXNJ1NpXg=

$ ulimit -l
64
$ sudo bash
# echo "*   -     memlock   1048576" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
```

log out now.

```
$ ulimit -l
1048576

$ echo test  | sha256 -s test | base64
NyaDNd1pMQRb3N+SYj/4GaZCRLU9DnRtQ4eXNJ1NpXg=
```

no more tears!!

I'm guessing this warning is about the corner case of having your secrets paged out of memory, and someone finding it latter in tmp space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `sha256 -x`. From the man page: "If the -x option is given then the hash will be printed as a string of hexadecimal digits." (https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/hashalot/sha256.1.en.html)